# How to calculate the mean/median/standard deviation of multiple matrices in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Could you provide some solutions or suggestions for the following problem?

If I have a dictionary which contains three pandas dataframe, how should I calculate the mean/median/standard deviation of the three dataframes in the dictionary?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,4)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,4)))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,4)))
df_dict = {'a': df1, 'b': df2, 'c':df3}
```

(the output matrix should still be a 3x4 matrix)

```
(df1+df2+df3)/3
          0         1         2         3
0  5.666667  5.000000  3.333333  3.000000
1  4.000000  1.666667  6.666667  4.333333
2  3.000000  3.666667  4.666667  4.333333
```

Since I have a dictionary containing 50+ dataframes in reality, an efficient approach is appreciated.
Hopefully, no simple loop.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
(pd.concat(df_dict).groupby(level=1)
                   .agg(['mean','median','std'])
                   .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
                   .sort_index(level=0, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
       mean                               median                std                              
          0         1         2         3      0  1  2  3         0         1         2         3
0  5.333333  4.333333  8.666667  4.666667      4  5  9  4  2.309401  2.081666  0.577350  4.041452
1  3.333333  5.666667  3.333333  4.666667      3  5  3  4  0.577350  1.154701  3.511885  2.081666
2  4.333333  2.000000  2.666667  8.333333      4  1  2  8  3.511885  2.645751  2.081666  0.577350
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(pd.DataFrame({k:v.stack() for k,v in df_dict.items()} )
   .T.agg(['mean','std','median'])
   .T.unstack()
)
```